# Detect if object is Ember Data or not

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

In Ember.js, I need to write a function that behaves differently depending on whether an object is an Ember Data object, or something else (Ember Object, plain JSON object, etc.). Is there a way to determine whether an object is Ember Data or not?

```
myfunction(myObject) {
    if(isEmberData(myObject)) {
        // Do stuff
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try with `myObject instanceof Ember.Object` since Ember Data merely returns an instance of an Ember Object.

Comment: That only tells me if it's an Ember Object. There are lots of Ember Objects that aren't Ember Data, and I need to be able to tell them apart.

Comment: You can also check if the object has the `store` property which belongs to ember-data.

Comment: Or by injecting store, you can also do a comparison like `this.get('collection.type') === this.get('store').modelFor('model-name')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple

```
if (obj instanceof DS.Model) {}
```

Should do the trick.